# Enable text selection on a website using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I know that typing
`javascript:void(document.oncontextmenu=null)` allows users to enable right click on a webpage

and `javascript:void(document.onselectstart=null)` should enable text selection if i'm correct?

but I tried typing these on http://www.pcworld.co.uk/gbuk/laptops-netbooks/laptops/apple-laptops/apple-macbook-pro-15-with-retina-display-21576115-pdt.html and it won't work.

by the way I typed it in the console of Google Chrome browser.

Comment: Text selection already works fine for me on that site.

Answer (score 0):

@Pointy pointed out that text selection worked fine for him. I tried in a few browsers - in Google Chrome specifically, on mouse down, the cursor changes when one tries to select text on a particular part of the page, and it does not allow this. However, on Firefox, you are perfectly capable of selecting the text.

For your intents, use a different browser and select the text.

For all we know, that sight could have custom javascript and logic preventing text selection, though its pretty lame that it doesn't work cross browser. But this custom logic is probably why your above mentioned commands aren't working.